# How to create single Kotlin flow function with multiple asynchronous functions

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

There are multiple async functions that depends one on another.

Consider functions functionA(), functionB(), functionC().

FunctionB will be called based on response callback from functionA, functionC will be called based the response callback from the functionB.

Now i want to send the result of each function as stream using flows function in Kotlin.

Any suggestions to achieve above functionality?

Thanks
Satya

Comment: Do you mean you want a Flow of the results of functionC, or do all three functions return the same type and you want a flow of each result sequentially? And are you also asking how to trigger the repeated calling of these functions or do you already have a Flow of inputs for functionA?

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour4,     1. all three functions return the same type and i want a flow of each result sequentially 

2. how to trigger A, that take care of triggering B on success, and trigger C on success of B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straight-forward with the `flow` builder. When you collect this Flow, it will call each of the functions, one after the other.

```
val results: Flow<ResultType> = flow {
    emit(functionA())
    emit(functionB())
    emit(functionC())
}
```

I'm not sure if you're saying the results should be based on the return values of the previous function calls. If so, then you can use if statements.

```
val results: Flow<ResultType> = flow {
    val resultA = functionA()
    if (!resultA.someCriteria) {
        return@flow
    }
    emit(resultA)
    val resultB = functionB(resultA)
    emit(resultB)
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually not return type, based on callback that received from any api call asynchronously. In functionA, i will make an api call, if i receive success call back, then i will proceed with functionB, at the same time every success callback result should be emitted.

Comment: From your comment, I can't tell. Are you still unsure how to do it? Your callback-based functions should be converted into suspend functions so you can call them from other suspend functions (such as the `flow` builder) sequentially.

Comment: its not recommend to use flow with this kind of problems because the suspend function maybe lunch a new coroutine or change the context... and thats prohibited for flow builder >>> we should use callbckFlow

Comment: I'm not sure what possible failure case you are describing or how `callbackFlow` would be any different in its behavior such that it would solve the failure, as we are just calling suspend functions, which presumably follow coroutine conventions that permit them to be called from any context. As with any code you write, don't call functions with side effects if you don't want those side effects.